# Python: create pivot table as numpy 2d-array from two lists

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following lists.

```
list_1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
list_2 = ["D", "A", "B"]
```

And I want to create a [numpy 2d-array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy.ndarray) that would work as a pivot table. The columns should be values from `list_1`, rows should be values from `list_2`, and values should be booleans saying if the values are/are not equal. The result should look like this.

```
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.]])
```

I have managed to write the code on my own, but I don't think my solution is the elegant one. I hope there is some built in numpy function for this that would make things simpler. Can you help me with that, please?

My code is following.

```
import numpy as np

list_1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
list_2 = ["D", "A", "B"]

my_array = np.zeros((len(list_2), len(list_1)))

for i, val in enumerate(list_2):
    my_array[i] = val == np.array(list_1)

print(my_array)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy broadcasting:

```
list_1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
list_2 = ["D", "A", "B"]

my_array = (np.array(list_1) == np.array(list_2)[:,None]).astype(int)
```

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

NB. if you really want booleans (True/False), leave out the `.astype(int)`:

```
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]])
```